# rpmsign with CLI password prompt

Tags: command-line, scripting, password, rpm, gnupg

I working on a Fedora 25 (F25) workstation, the KDE spin. I'm writing some scripts to perform automated testing.

One of the automated tests involves invoking the RPMSIGN(8) program which in turn invokes GPG(1) to attach a digital signature to some RPM files I am creating. Of course, GPG uses pinentry (PIN entry) to prompt the human to enter the passphrase for the RPM signing key (an RSA key pair). I want to take the human out of the loop and fully automate the task of supplying the passphrase for the RPM signing key.( And yes, I know about the security implications. This is simply an automated test environment and not a production host, so I'm not overly concerned about security. In the production version the user will  manually enter the RPM signing key's password.)

In the past I used an EXPECT(1) script that waited for GPG to ouptut the text "Enter pass phrase:" to the console, and then the EXPECT script would enter the pass phrase and on I'd go. Worked great.

In F25 the pinentry feature breaks my existing EXPECT-based solution for automated entry of the passphrase for the RPM signing key.

When I run RPMSIGN in a GUI console window on this F25 host, GPG uses pinentry to pop up a GUI dialog box that asks the user (me) to enter the passphrase for the RPM signing key. This pinentry behavior, of course, interferes and prevents automated entry of the passphrase.

If I create a Bash script that momentarily unsets the DISPLAY environment variable, then I no longer get the GUI dialog,

```
#!/bin/bash
DISPLAY_SAVE=$DISPLAY
unset DISPLAY
rpmsign --resign "/path/to/test-1.0.0-1.fc25.noarch.rpm"
export DISPLAY=$DISPLAY_SAVE
```

but now I get an ncurses version of the dialog on the console:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| Please enter the passphrase to unlock the OpenPGP secret key:  |
| "Testing (rpm-sign)"                                           |
| 1024-bit RSA key, ID 0123456789ABCDEF,                         |
| created 2016-12-02.                                            |
|                                                                |
|                                                                |
| Passphrase: __________________________________________________ |
|                                                                |
|         <OK>                                    <Cancel>       |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Again, pinentry-curses's console "dialog" interferes and prevents automated entry of the passphrase.

I don't want to permanently modify or disable the pinentry modules; I just want to disable them temporarily to get back to GPG's CLI prompt "Enter pass phrase:" (or whatever that prompt string is now) without pinentry interfering.

Any suggestions for fully automating the entry of the RPM signing key's passphrase via the CLI without pinentry interference?

Answer (score 11):

Thanks to @Joe Damato for pointing me toward the `gpg-preset-passphrase` utility. The solution described below was developed and tested on a Fedora 25 host with `gnupg2-2.1.x` installed.

(n.b. I haven't yet figured out how to determine the RPM signing key's keygrip value on platforms running older versions of GnuPG because they don't support the `--with-keygrip` option. If someone would like to comment on a solution for this, please do.)

Ensure `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf` contains the line.

```
allow-preset-passphrase
```

After modifying `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf` reload the gpg-agent.

```
$ gpg-connect-agent reloadagent /bye
OK
```

List your GPG keys to obtain the eight hexidecimal digit key ID for your RPM signing key. In this excample, the key ID is `0123ABCD`.

```
$ gpg --list-keys
/home/me/.gnupg/pubring.gpg
-----------------------------------
pub   1024R/0123ABCD 2015-06-13
uid                  Test (rpm-sign)
```

Get the keygrip code for the RPM signing key. (n.b. On the RHEL 7.2 and Fedora 20 hosts I use for testing, the `GPG2(1)` program on those hosts didn't recognize the `--with-keygrip` option.)

```
$ gpg2 --with-keygrip -K 0123ABCD
sec   rsa1024 2015-06-13 [SCEA]
      0A1B2C3D4E5F6A7B8C9D0E0F1A2B3C4D0123ABCD
      Keygrip = 2EACA0C5A4B46168EB91970B6715AF1AA52968BE
uid           [ unknown] Test (rpm-sign)
```

Cache the passphrase for the RPM signing key. In the command line shown below, replace `'PASSPHRASE'` with the actual passphrase for the RPM signing key.

```
$ /usr/libexec/gpg-preset-passphrase --passphrase 'PASSPHRASE' --preset 2EACA0C5A4B46168EB91970B6715AF1AA52968BE
```

### :: TEST ::

Create a test RPM file that is not signed. Verify that the test RPM file is not signed.

```
$ rpm --checksig test-1.0.0-1.f25.noarch.rpm
test-1.0.0-1.fc25.noarch.rpm: sha1 md5 OK
```

Verify that `RPMSIGN(8)` uses the cached password--i.e., that `RPMSIGN(8)` does not prompt you to enter the passphrase for the RPM signing key--when signing the test RPM file.

```
$ rpmsign --resign test-1.0.0-1.f25.noarch.rpm
```

Verify that the test RPM file is signed.

```
$ rpm --checksig test-1.0.0-1.f25.noarch.rpm
test-1.0.0-1.fc25.noarch.rpm: rsa sha1 (md5) pgp md5 OK
```

### :: ADDENDUM 1 (2016-12-17) ::

According to this [GnuPG Issue 2331 webpage](https://bugs.gnupg.org/gnupg/issue2331):

> gpg1 does not known about keygrips.  Instead of the keygrip, gpg1 uses the fingerprint as cacheid for gpg-agent.  The agent's command GET_PASSPHRAE, as used by gpg1, uses a different cache mode from what gpg-preset-passphrases uses.  Thus even if you replace the keygrip with the fingerprint of the (sub)key, it won't work.

For what it's worth, I've done some testing with GnuPG version 2.0.x on RHEL7 hosts and `gpg-preset-passphrase` doesn't seem to be supported. I can only get `gpg-preset-passphrase` to work with GnuPG version 2.1.x.

### References

[GnuPG ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GnuPG)

Comment: This answer helped me a low. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 6):

By adding/modifying the `%__gpg_sign_cmd` macro in your `.rpmmacros` file, you can tell gpg to read the passphrase from a file. Use `rpm --showrc` to see what your current `%__gpg_sign_cmd` looks like, and then put that into your `.rpmmacros` file, with the following addition:

```
--batch --pinentry-mode loopback --passphrase-file /path/to/passphrase-file
```

Make sure to end each line except the last with `\` if you have a multiline value.

This will cause gpg to not prompt in any way for the passphrase, and instead read it from the defined file. This poses a **security risk** of course, so consider if this is something you want to do, and take any necessary steps to secure it (e.g. ownership and permission).

Example of full `%__gpg_sign_cmd` in `.rpmmacros`:

```
%__gpg_sign_cmd %{__gpg} \
    gpg --no-verbose --no-armor --batch --pinentry-mode loopback \
    --passphrase-file /path/to/passphrase-file \
    %{?_gpg_digest_algo:--digest-algo %{_gpg_digest_algo}} \
    --no-secmem-warning \
    -u "%{_gpg_name}" -sbo %{__signature_filename} %{__plaintext_filename}
```

Signing a package:

```
$ rpm --checksig somepackage.rpm 
somepackage.rpm: sha1 md5 OK

$ rpmsign --addsign somepackage.rpm
somepackage.rpm:

$ rpm --checksig somepackage.rpm 
somepackage.rpm: rsa sha1 (md5) pgp md5 OK
```

Comment: Confirm this worked in CentOS 8 (gnupg2-2.2.)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me on CentOS 7. I have tried defining it in `~/.rpmmacros` and on the command line like `rpm --define '__gpg_sign_cmd ...' --addsign /path/to/rpm` neither one works. I still get the "Enter pass phrase" prompt :(

Answer (score 4):

One solution to this sort of problem is to use `gpg-agent`, which manages GPG secret keys. You can use that tool in conjunction with `gpg-preset-passphrase` to seed the passphrase into the `gpg-agent` cache. Read more about gpg-agent [here](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg-devel/Invoking-GPG_002dAGENT.html#Invoking-GPG_002dAGENT). This will allow you to avoid needing to enter a passphrase manually so you can perform your automated tasks.

BTW, I wrote a helpful blog post about [GPG signing and verifying RPM Packages and YUM repositories](https://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2014/11/24/howto-gpg-sign-verify-rpm-packages-yum-repositories/) that you might find useful, too.

Comment: Thanks @Joe. I'll experiment with the gpg-preset-passphrase utility to see if I can get a solution that works for me. FWIW, on my F25 host the gpg-preset-passphrase executable is installed in /usr/libexec/, in case this helps someone else locate it on their box.

Answer (score 1):

To automate it pass your PIN/Pass via a gpg command line (this may expose it via proc params while gpg is running) or via a temp file a to the gpg extra args, and then shred the file. Either way the risk of exposure is mostly for advanced threat models.

Via params:

```
rpm --define "_gpg_sign_cmd_extra_args --pinentry-mode loopback --passphrase $PIN" --addsign <file>
```

Via temp file:

```
tempf=$(mktemp)
echo $PIN > $tempf
rpm --define "_gpg_sign_cmd_extra_args --pinentry-mode loopback --passphrase-file $tmpf" --addsign <file>
shred $tempf
```

Answer (score 0):

For CentOS7 (and I guess RedHat7) with GPG 2.0, the `pinentry-mode` and `gpg-preset-passphrase` is not working.

I manage to make it working using [Expect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect).

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

### rpm-sign.exp -- Sign RPMs by sending the passphrase.
 
spawn rpm --addsign {*}$argv
expect -exact "Enter pass phrase: "
send -- "Secret passphrase\r"
expect eof

## end of rpm-sign.exp
```

Usage

```
$ ./rpm-sign.exp PACKAGE-FILE
```

Credits to Aaron S. Hawley [GPG signing RPMs unattended](https://aaronhawley.livejournal.com/10615.html)

Comment: In CentOS 7 the issue isn't that GPG won't respect pinentry-mode, it's that rpmsign itself is [asking for the password](https://github.com/rpm-software-management/rpm/blob/rpm-4.11.3-release/rpmsign.c#L123) with getpass(). In my testing I was able to get it talk to the GPG agent if I just hit enter. For wholly unattended signing you might be able to suppress the prompt by running rpmsign without an attached tty (which would likely make getpass() simply fail).